# bitbucket git push not permitted

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket

i am trying to push code to bitbucket account from eclipse, where i am getting error `*"push not permitted"*`, i am able to clone and get files from the bitbucket repository.

i am facing problem while pushing to upstream command in eclipse git, am getting below error

```
git@bitbucket.org:codedevelopers/coder.git push not permitted
```

i am not admin, but i have read and write access granted by my admin, i have tried both ssh and https push, i am getting same error.  i am stuck with this issue. i have another user who is admin ,can able to push his code to bitbucket.

Thanks for your replies

Comment: Assuming you copy and pasted the error, perhaps you have it wrong.  Should "codedevlopers" be "codedevelopers" (notice the 'e' between the 'v' and 'l')?

Comment: @jszakmeister you are correct, it was typo error, corrected

Comment: Did you check the url in Eclipse?  Is the same error there?  I ask because that might be the actual problem.  It's easy to overlook a typo like that. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Ssh would work if your public key was added to the repo admin ssh key management page.
- https should work if you are using your bitbucket username and email, provided the admin did grant you access *using that exact email*
  So try:

  ```
  git remote set-url origin https://myusername@bitbucket.org/codedevelopers/coder
  ```

(replace `myusername` by your BitBucket account username)

See "[Grant users and groups access](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Grant+users+and+groups+access)"

[image: https://confluence.atlassian.com/download/attachments/304578655/send_invite.png?version=2&modificationDate=1379979323235&api=v2&effects=drop-shadow]

Double-check with that admin which email he/she used to grant you write access to this repo.

---

A mentioned by [jszakmeister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/683080/jszakmeister) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21696015/bitbucket-git-push-not-permitted#comment32805788_21696015), look out for a **typo** in the url you end up using.

For instance, there is a user [bitbucket.org/codedevelopr](https://bitbucket.org/codedevelopr) (instead of '`codedevelopers`').